# A predicative adjective in an atributive clause OR a postpositive adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, clauses

Example: These are/were the images presented by us.

Is "presented" in this case a postpositive adjective or a predicative adjective in an attributive clause?

In case "presented" is a verb here, can I use it without using subject, like in the example above?

Comment: _Presented_ is a past participle reduced by _Whiz_-deletion  from a relative clause, a transform  of _the images **which  were** presented_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *These are the images* [*which were presented by us*].
>
> [2] *These are the images* [*presented by us*].

Compare the two examples. In [1] the bracketed element is a **relative clause** modifying "images".

In [2] the bracketed clause also modifies "images", but this time it's a **past-participial clause**, not a relative one. Semantically they are similar, of course, but we don't call [2] a relative clause since there's no possibility of inserting a relative phrase (cf. *"These are the images which presented by us".). I don’t want to be positing a deleted verb.

Some people call [2] a 'reduced relative clause', but that term is a misnomer. The crucial property of relative clauses is the presence of some relativised element (overt or covert) that is anaphorically linked to a noun or nominal, and this property is not present here.